# "No data found." text in Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I would like to do the report using iReport which can but does not have to display rows. How can I force Jasper Reports to display the text "No data found." when the query returns no data. I would like to have the same header as when there are rows.

I know I should change the report property "When No Data" to display something but I don't know how to implement the condition for no rows.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have found it out myself.

This could be done by following these steps:

1. Add the "`No Data`" section from the sections list in the "`Report Inspector`". Right click it and choose "`Add Band`". After this, new section will be added to your report.
2. Add any content to the new added section, e.g. "`No Data found`." message (if you would like the same header as in "normal" report, you have to copy it from the "Header" section to "`No Data`" section).

If you don't have the report property "`When No Data`" set to "`No Data Section`" set it so or follow these steps:

1. Display report property by right clicking on the report and choosing "`Properties`" from the displayed menu.
2. Find the section "`More...`" and in it you will see "When No Data" property, change it to "`No Data Section`".

After following the above, your report will show the "`No Data`" section when there will be no data, oterwise it will show the section as before.